# Unity: No animation event is fired when quickly pressing a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D video game project but I have a somewhat strange error in the character's attack. I've been using Unity for a short time...

When I press the attack button, an animation is played and a boolean variable is set to true. When the attack animation ends, it has an event in place that calls a function to change the boolean variable back to false.

**Main script added to player gameobject (MonoBehaviour):**

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKey(script_buttons.button_attack))
                {
                    gun_attacking = false;
                    player_animator.Play("gun_attack");
                }
}
```

**Event that is called when the weapon attack animation ends:**

```
void foot_gun_attack()
     {
       attack_script.gun_attacking = false;
     }
```

It works fine, but if I quickly press the attack button, there are times when the variable never goes to false, and the game goes crazy.

Is it unreliable to use events in the animations themselves? why does it fail and not change the boolean variable to false again?

I have partially fixed it by adding a State machine behavior script to the animation, and in said script, right in the OnStateExit function I change the variable to false. This works and the attack never misses no matter how fast you press the button, the problem? which forces me to have both at once, the animation event and the state machine behavior script. If I remove the event the vairable never goes false, if I remove the state machine behavior the variable does go false but fails every once in a while.

**Script on state machine behavior:**

```
override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
       attack_script.gun_attacking = false;

    }
```

The only way it won't fail is to set the variable to false in both places, which I think is crazy and shouldn't be normal behavior. The animation event should suffice and work fine, but why isn't it working correctly? I wouldn't like to have to limit button presses or add Timeouts, or would that be the only way?

Maybe it's my mistake or Unity problem, does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be that the animation never ends and goes to another state

The first way is that
When You can call the function you want when the animation starts, but in the coroutine, it waits for the animation time and then returns the bool to false.

or continue with your own method, but check and change this configuration in the transitions before and after that animation.

[image]

Especially try these 2 checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for answering. It turns out that my animations do not have a transition (joining arrows) and I am doing them through code and the Play event of the animator. When the attack animation ends, the event is triggered and the attack variable is set to false, then the idle animation is triggered. I don't have Has Exit Time in this case, I'm creating the project without transitions, as explained in this video: https://youtu.be/nBkiSJ5z-hE